# Android - Import Java Class into Activity

Tags: java, android, import

I have a java class called `Constants` filled with variables. And currently if I want to use that variable in an activity I have to use it like this.

```
Constants.variable = "blah blah";
```

Is there a way to import my `Constants` class into my activity so that I can just use it like a normal variable like this

```
variable = "blah blah";
```

I have tried

```
import com.myname.appname.Constants;
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 6):

considering **Constants.variable** is a static variable

```
import static com.myname.appname.Constant.*;
```

this will import all you static variables in you current namespace only the static variable

```
import static com.myname.appname.Constant.variable;
```

now you can use variable like a normal variable

Comment: so the * will get all the variables and/ or I can specify just one?

Comment: putting * will import all the static variable.. .that totally depends on you.. u only want to import specific variable or all the variable

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
import com.myname.appname.Constants;
```

Are you using an IDE?

Also, they way you have stated is how you are suppose to use a Constants class. But you are not suppose to assign anything... because the variable are suppose to be constant, ie. static final

Comment: that what I did try I'm using android studio

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare "variable" as static and import the class as static by following syntax

```
    import static com.myname.appname.Constants.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to import my constants class into my activity so that I
>   can just use it like a normal variable like this

I dont think so, its not what `import` for.

See this SO question : [Meaning of the import statement in a Java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903166/meaning-of-import-statement-in-java-file)